# Heroku CLI not working within pycharm terminal

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I am new to django and working on a django project, using pycharm as the editor. I am trying to deploy it on heroku. I installed heroku cli on my windows os, and tested it using command prompt, and it is working. But within pycharm's terminal, when I type "heroku", it does not recognize it. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried restarting pycharm? if not please do so.

Comment: Yes I restarted it several times, yet still not working

Answer (score 0):

If Heroku is working on CMD there are no hidden intergration for pycharm,it should work.
Kindly check if the working envrioment is set,

(venv) C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>heroku

if the problem persist install the heroku jetbrain integration for here

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6659-heroku-integration/

Comment: It was working fine for my another project, but here it started the issue. Right now I'm working from windows command line